# How Do I configure Formik error messages and validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have recently adopted a React JS codebase that does not use best practices for clarity and maintainability (entire page is 18000 lines of code in a single file). The codebase heavily relies on Formik, along with Yup, to do data Validation and error handling. The page (called the UWF) allows users to input line items from an invoice and submit them for processing. When submitting, it will validate the data using the FormikHelpers.validateForm. I have been unable to find accurate documentation for this method. I do know the method returns a "FormikErrors" object (also little documentation) in JSON form which contains the following line:

*"transactions.payments.transactionItems[0].transactionLineItems[0].taxCode must be one of the following values: I0, O0, U1, U2"*

The error occurs when attempting to submit the form with a Tax Code of "Q7" selected. This is very odd, because these tax codes only appear in one place in the entire codebase:

```
transactionItems: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
...
          transactionLineItems: yup
            .array()
            .of(
              yup.object().shape({
...                
                taxCode: yup.mixed().oneOf(["I0", "O0", "U1", "U2", "Q7"]).required("Tax Code is required"),
...
              })
            )
            .min(1, "Atleast 1 line item is required")
        })
      )
```

Ellipsis added to shorten code.
You can see that Q7 is included in this list of approved values. And yet it does not allow me to submit. In addition, the words "must be one of the following values" do not appear anywhere in the code base.

I am not a front-end developer, so I am at a loss. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup works as expected.
You can check it here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-validation-test-forked-q8sr6s?file=/src/index.js

Please check the logic of Formik.

Comment: @JasonMing You are correct, and this is the right answer, but I cannot give you credit on a comment. After finally getting React Dev Tools installed (my company is very slow and stubborn) I realized none of the changes I have made have ended up in Production. Guess I need to research how pipelines work. Thank you!

If you add this comment as an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Thank you. I added this comment as an answer.